# Visual Studio Code on Windows server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, windows-server-2008

Can I install Visual Studio Code on Windows server 2008 ?

I am a developer but I sent the information to my administrators and they told me that the setup file crashes after launched

I get seput file from hee https://code.visualstudio.com/download

> procesor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6142 CPU @ 2.60Ghz - 2.59 GHz

> RAM: 8 GB

> 64-bit

> virtual machine

> 1 CPU - 2 cores

> Windows Server 2008

Comment: Does the Server/VM only have a single core/cpu?

Comment: @Otter 
procesor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6142 CPU @ 2.60Ghz - 2.59 GHz
RAM: 8 GB
64-bit

Comment: Is this 2008 server a physical machine or a virtual machine?

Comment: @Otter virtual machine

Comment: How many CPU/cores are assigned to the virtual machine?

Comment: @Otter - 1 CPU - 2 cores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time answering here so bare with my vintage reply formatting. (also pardon that i couldn't capture screen due to server is on a intranet that not accessible on this device causing a long reply)

Being a unfortunate fellow that need to work on legacy Systems and Application frequently, i happen to have a fresh 2008R2 server recently setup by my team's Server Admin with following specs:

> **processor:** Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5220 CPU @ 2.20Ghz - 2.19 GHz ,
> **OS:** Windows Server 2008R2 x64 ,
> **RAM:** 8GB

The versions that is able to install was **1.70.3**,which is the same version that is the **last supporting versions for Windows 7 as well**,if you happen to need to work on devices using that OS version.

although i'm uncertain whether it is a VM or not, i'd like to point out a few more things that your question did not cover but need to consider:

- The **installer version  (System setup vs User Setup)**

aside from the x64 |x86 | ARM installer differences, as you've not mentioned which versions of the build and which exact setup installer you sent to your admin, i've first replied which **build version** successfully installed on 2008R2, which as of writing the latest build was **1.73.0** and on run,it pop up a error message as follow regardless of System/User Setup:

> This Program does not support the version of windows your computer is running.

in our current case that we want specific previous versions installer, [VScode FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions) on previous versions have a URL lists that enables you to download a specific build version of your preferred setup. For my case (and also refer below to exactly why this one), i've go for **System setup**, and i know the aprox. supporting version was **~1.70.0**, so i used the link as below and replace the {version} to start:

> [https://update.code.visualstudio.com/{version}/win32-x64/stable](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/%7Bversion%7D/win32-x64/stable)

- Active Domain, Multiple user sessions etc.

[Per VSCode requirements](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements) page stated,

> *VS Code does not support multiple simultaneous users using the software on the same machine, including shared virtual desktop
> infrastructure machines or a pooled Windows/Linux Virtual Desktop host
> pool.*

as im not sure do you work solo or do have fellow colleagues to code on the server at the same time, you might need to reconsider to install using **user** or **System** setup.

if your intentions are to use exclusively on a specific AD account, then user setup should probably be good enough.

however, if the intentions was to setup say a shared Remote desktop connections on the VM that allows multiple RDC sessions simultaneously for coding,programming etc., so you intend to install a **system setup** to allow all users on said server to be able to use VScode, then you might run into the problem the VScode requirements stated it does not support.

in addition, as i was remote connected as **administrator** , when using a 1.70.2 *user setup* ,a different warning message as follow was thrown:

> This user Installer is not meant to be run as Administrator. If you would like to install VS Code for all users in this system, download the system Installer instead.Are you sure you want to continue?

as the installer itself also checks with the operator on this matter, your admin may have skipped on the exact reasons why the install failed and just told you the installer crashed.

if you absolutely need VScode to run on the server but can't install for reasons, the last resort (aside from going for alternatives like notepad++) is to [Setup a Portable Mode builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) on your own workstation/devices first, then upload the package to the server and use it from there.

i wouldn't go into too much detail in that as this reply already span for a starwars trilogy length but keep in mind, version limitations still apply, and whatever add-ons you need, you need to download them first before bundle it into the package to upload and run on your server.

Anyone that is a System admin or infrastructure architects , do correct me on my novice understanding on Server settings etc. as although i'm primarily a programmer, i did end up touching a lot more things that i'm not specialized into over the few years of vendor career work so there bound to be incorrect/inaccurate concepts i spilled. cheers.